# Texto em inglês no aviso de que o post foi editado

Tags: bug, tradução

Após iniciar a edição de um post, caso haja alguma edição confirmada após você iniciar uma outra edição, um alerta é exibido com esta notificação.

Já havia acontecido antes mas eu não tinha percebido a falta de tradução. Me ocorreu novamente ao iniciar a edição da [pergunta de um iniciante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295118/duplicar-uma-planilha-atrav%C3%A9s-da-altera%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-c%C3%A9lula) com problemas de formatação:

[image: Exemplo de ocorrência]

O texto, neste caso é: *"This post has been edited 1 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit."*

Vi que aqui no meta tem alguns posts notificando problemas de tradução em alguns pontos e uma certa recorrência do mesmo bug que aparentemente ainda está sendo tratada, mas não encontrei nenhuma notificação específica para este ponto.